# Why the disparity between the screencodes and the character codes?

Tags: commodore-64

The Commodore 64, and possibly others, I don't know, have character codes (These map integers to characters, in the same way that ASCII does) and there are screen codes (The offset which the VIC-II will use to look up the bitmap in the character set).

The character codes are used in file names, I guess BASIC tokens etc also. The screen codes are *only* used when putting some letter on the screen! [Then there are routines to convert between them](http://codebase64.org/doku.php?id=base:petscii_to_screencode&s[]=screencodes). Presumably, the ROM also needs to do exactly this thing.

So is there a reason why not put the bitmaps in the character ROM in the same order that the characters are laid out by PETSCII? That would save people from having to do this daft, daft conversion.

Comment: This "daft" conversion continues to this day.  To look up a glyph in some modern font file formats, one takes the character code point and runs it through a transformation (usually some sort of map embedded in the font file) to yield the symbol index for the actual glyph data.  Glyph order in the font is not character code point order in the character set.  At least one file format allows a many-to-one mapping, too, for saving space.

Comment: @JdeBP you mean so that a Cyrillic a and Latin a can occupy the same space? That makes a lot of sense actually. That kind of thing could have worked quite nicely actually if ever they did a Russian Commodore 64.

Comment: [If they have identical bit representations](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/4b529e40b9b8c5bcd0a4bc923a168c7988b72748/usr/src/cmd/vtfontcvt/vtfontcvt.c#L279), yes.

Comment: @Wilson [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOST_10859#7-bit_code:_Cyrillic_and_Latin_upper-case_letters) is an example. They've overdone it, unifying Y and У; luckily stopping short of unifying W and Ш.

Comment: @LeoB. Did any Soviet or Russian homecomputers with bitmap fonts ever use ГОСТ 10859 encoding for this? Like a БК or ДВК or something? or do you mean that Commodore really did release a Russian C=64?

Comment: @Wilson No, by the time home computers appeared, the ASCII-like [KOI-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KOI-7), specifically [the uppercase-only variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KOI-7#KOI-7_N2) and [KOI-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KOI-8) were widespread. БК and ДВК used KOI-8. The clones of Western 8-bit micros used KOI-7, as it was relatively straightforward to replace lowercase Latin with uppercase Cyrillic, sacrificing a few punctuation characters which are in the 0x60-0x7F range in the process, but as they were not used in BASIC, that went smoothly.

Comment: Since this *is* retrocomputing, maybe Commodore did it like that so you young whippersnappers with your personal computers could experience the glorious excitement of yesteryear, where every single device on the same computer implemented its own character code :-)

Comment: In short, PETSCII has control codes that have no printable I.E. no pixel pattern to display, and also regular printable characters.  
Display codes only represent printable characters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the C64, there's a simple reason (probably among others): Control characters vs. reverse video.

There are two character sets of 256 characters and two fonts of 256 glyphs. Both have the following in common:

- The font has 128 glyphs twice, in normal and reversed display
- The character set on the other hand has quite a few "control characters", like clear screen, issue newline, change color, and also enable/disable reverse video

Therefore, a 1:1 mapping simply isn't possible.

The system is however designed in a way enabling you to use your own font, and you can encode it however you like -- a while back, I created a font using the IBM CP-437 encoding, this is quite nice for e.g. on-screen docs.

Answer (score 9):

Most microcomputers treat character codes and screen codes
differently. This is because they serve different functions and
arranging them both the same would compromise the functionality or
implementation of one or the other.

#### Screen Codes

The function of a screen code is to encode, at a position in the frame
buffer, what particular glyph should be shown by the video system at
that position on the screen. Additionally the code may include
information modifying the display of the glyph, such as a bit
indicating whether the glyph should be displayed in positive (white on
black background) or inverted (black on white background) form.

The patterns to generate the glyphs are usually stored in ROM (though
sometimes RAM) and looked up by address. If the screen code directly
encodes the (usually low portion of) the address in some of its bits
this makes simpler the hardware doing the lookup of the glyph from the
screen code. This is desirable to reduce both the hardware cost and
the complexity of the system. (The reason cost reduction is desirable
is obvious. Reducing complexity reduces the time spent on design and
debugging and also reduces the chance that a bug will go out in the
final product.)

This tends to make screen codes map fairly closely to the hardware
used to generate the glyphs. For example, if there are 64 glyphs
available in the system (typically numbers, punctuation and upper-case
letters), they're likely to be stored at addresses whose lowest six
bits are hexadecimal $00 through $3F (binary xx000000 through
xx111111).

You'll note a difference if you compare the above to [the ASCII
character set encoding](https://github.com/0cjs/sedoc/blob/master/ascii.txt), where this range, with all the bits
above the lowest six set the same, covers either:

- the (non-printing) control characters, punctuation and numbers
  ($00-$3F), with no letters at all, or
- the upper case and lower case letters (and a bit of different
  punctuation), with no numbers at all.

#### Character Codes

Character codes have two characteristics that are generally different
from convenient screen code numberings as described above.

First, they almost invariably have non-printing *control characters*
which, instead of requesting that a glyph be printed, request some
other action on the part of the printing device. For example, in ASCII
the `LF` ($0A) character generally indicates to a printer or screen
that it should print subsequent characters on the next line.¹ Control
characters are also often used as instructions to code that is
processing characters; ASCII `NUL` ($00) is often used to signal the
end of a string, for example.

Control characters are unnecessary in screen codes, however, and a
non-printing code simply wastes space in the list of screen codes.

Second, it's common to want to use a standard character set and
encoding (e.g., ASCII or Unicode UTF-8) for compatibility and easy
data interchange with other systems.

Using a standard fixes the codes you can use, and often in a way
inconvenient for use as screen codes, as we saw with ASCII in the
previous section.

#### Summary

So, for the reasons described above, generally screen codes are easier
to do in one way, and character codes in another. Fortunately this is
not difficult to handle: most microcomputers provide a small routine
that will convert character codes to screen codes. A routine to "print
a character" is generally wanted anyway, since it lets commonly used
logic such as "print a character just after the last one printed on
the screen" be handled in one place (which also avoids co-ordination
problems between different routines that both print), so adding this
conversion is usually a trivial cost.

---

¹<sub>This is a simplified example; what the control characters do is
often far more complex and system-dependent than described here. But
the general idea is the same.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

> The Commodore 64, and possibly others, I don't know, have character codes (These map integers to characters, in the same way that ASCII does) and there are screen codes

To start with, this includes the Apple II - as well as several others.

> So is there a reason why not put the bitmaps in the character ROM in the same order that the characters are laid out by PETSCII? That would save people from having to do this daft, daft conversion.

For one, isn't there an OS to do that job? (*1)

The main reason is simple: **Rearranging Them Saves Hardware.**

The other is that rearranging them enables additional features.

---

For example, the **Apple II** had only a ROM for 64 different glyphs. Arranging them in a way to suit ASCII encoding, would mean that ROM space for 128 glyphs would be needed - or additional hardware to do the transformation on the fly. That would have asked for a ROM chip double the size (*2) or some clever logic doing the transformation on the fly. Replacing a rather expensive chip with a few lines of machine code seems like a good trade-off. Especially one in line with Woz' constant struggle to cut down the chip count. Isn't it?

Similarly, **Sinclair's [ZX80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX80_character_set)/[ZX81](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX81_character_set)** character set follow the same reasoning of cutting down the needed ROM space. Except here, 11 punctuation characters were switched for graphic symbols to allow for 4 pixel per character cell graphics.

The **Sinclair ZX Spectrum** extends this to [128 codepoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX_Spectrum_character_set) to include full ASCII charset with lower case and all (*3) punctuation plus the drawing symbols.

On the **PET** the reasoning was a bit different. While it had a [character ROM](http://www.6502.org/users/sjgray/computer/cbmchr/cbmchr.html) holding 256 glyphs, they were organized as two character sets of 128 each, so standard character handling could be kept as 7 bit. Further, the [PETSCII encoding](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/petscii.pdf) corresponded to what the keyboard delivered, and the ROM was organized accordingly.

So while it made sense for the first PET, the C64 and other 8-bit Commodores only inherited it for compatibility.

---

Bottom line, by separating the functionality of having ASCII on the software side, while having a different hardware representation on the CRT controller side, enables ways of optimization - much like any other abstract interface does.

---

*1 - **NEVER. EVER. Assume** that a certain binary representation of your data is the same over all steeps of processing or across different devices and networks. This and assuming that binary will be unharmed in transmission are eventually the two main reason for bugs ... well, after off-by-one that is.

- Never assume that binary representation of (character) data has a particular sequence or order.
- There  are representations where he binary value of B is lower than the value for A, while C may be again lower, or higher or inbetween.
- Always keep in mind that recoding can and will happen.
- Never calculate between codesets. Use translation tables.

*2 - Or at least an additional half the size answering to the missing 31/32 glyphs twice.

*3 - Within reason.

Comment: "For one, isn't there an OS to do that job?" I'd have thought so. But as you can see, someone found it necessary to write his own code to do this conversion. I haven't looked, bu so I guess the ROM routine isn't usable/convenient for whatever reason.

Comment: Or he just wants to do it ... like in assuming everyone else is less capable. A common varation of the Not-Invented-Here syndrom.

Comment: The Apple ]['s output routine doesn't actually use ASCII codes, but instead expects to be passed values 128 higher than the desired ASCII code.  This was probably done to save a few bytes of ROM, but makes it needlessly difficult for something like a printer card to support 8-bit graphics data.

Comment: @supercat It's exactly the same reason as with the PET. A (unread) keypress is on the Apple II signaled with a set high bit. So a keypress can be directly routed to COUT(1).

Comment: I had to downvote this 'answer' as it doesn't answer the question. How does it save hardware? This answer doesn't say. What are the additional features it enables? This answer doesn't say.

Also, this answer spends more time talking about unrelated systems which are irrelevant to answering the question.

Next, the PET doesn't have two sets of 128 characters, it has two sets of 256 characters using 4K of ROM.

Lastly, please look up the difference between 'were' and 'where'. It will only take two minutes of your life.

Comment: @Raffzahn: Does the PET not use the same character codes as the VIC-20/C64?  Those mostly use "old" ASCII for codes 0x20-0x5F.  As for the Apple's rationale, I don't see any "savings" beyond two bytes in the character-get routine, which one will end up losing elsewhere anyway.

Comment: The ZX machines have a very different architecture though. The C64 which I asked about has a separate character ROM; it seems like if they wanted to cut hardware, they'd just put the font elsewhere, and copy it into RAM. So I think your argument doesn't make that much sense.

Comment: @TimLocke The original PET had a 2 KiB Character ROM. 4 KiB is only the SuperPET and European varaiations of later PET.

Comment: @Wilson "The Commodore 64, _and possibly others_" - to me this was asking for a generalized answer, not just for the C64. For the C64 it's simple, as it just took this mechanic from the PETs. Keep in mind, the C64 was designed in a manner of weeks. For a project in hurry you don't touch parts that work.

Comment: The inverted characters are generated in hardware on the PET (driven by the high bit and an inverter), so each of the two character sets only needs to contain 128 characters.

Comment: @RhialtosupportsMonica: I wonder why the VIC-20 and C64 video chips didn't include an option to do likewise?  That would have allowed a 4Kx8 ROM to be cut down to 2Kx8, which I would think would have been a noticeable cost savings.

Comment: @supercat: Neither the VIC nor the VIC-II video chips (used in VIC-20 and C64 respectively) were designed **for** those computers. Both were pre-existing designs which the intended target market being arcade machines, as far as I know. For those auto inversion wouldn't have been all that useful, I guess.

Comment: @TeaRex: Do you have any cite for that?  Arcade machines almost always used either black and white or RGB video, making the chroma circuitry in the VIC and VIC-II either superfluous or unsuitable.

Answer (score 2):

```
20 a = peek(1024 + x + y * 40)
30 if a > 127 then c$ = chr$(18):rem revers on
40 c$ = c$ + chr$ (a + 64 - (32 and a) + (64 and a) - (160 and a))
50 print c$
```

So line 40 changes screen code to character code. See +64, then -32 & -160 [that = 128 + 32] = 0, or -128 but then it's to be printed with revers on.

Comment: This does only explain the given 'how', not the 'why' the question asked.

Comment: @Raffzahn This is true, but the answer still does provide useful information related to the question that's not available in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just a case of two separate engineering teams solving a problem at different times or just not talking to each other.

Graphics guys worked out the easiest route for them, software kernal/basic team used their encoding - later on - someone merged the two with a lookup.

My guess is its just historical C64 wasn't going to change 'anything' for the sake of it - even tidiness - they probably only changed the software components they had to - for cost reasons (including dev and debugging)

Involve humans in a design over time and you get compromises - layers of compromises - the C64 was not the first computer these departments and groups inside CBM built so it gets some baggage.

Comment: NIce retrograde explanation, except it projects the approach of a large company onto a startup like setting. But the whole PET design was done by a team of only 6 people total. Including everything from keyboard to charset.